VB6 and VB.net has different outcomes with the same IF statements
I have the below IF statements tried on both VB6 and VB.net
Dim str As String = "，"

If str = "," Or str = "," Or str = """" Then
   'execute A
End If


When the str value is "，" (a full-width comma),
on VB6 A does not get executed while on VB.net it goes into the IF statement
and executes A.
The weird thing here is when I put this statement on watch when str = "，",
「 str = "," Or str = "," Or str = """" 」
it returns false, but still goes in the IF statement to execute A.
Does anyone has a clue to as to why this is happening?
I have tried changing from Or to orElse, and made sure the
Option Explicit On is there but its still the same result.
Im still new to VB.net so i might lack some foundation,
so any help is greatly appreciated.
Edit : I added the str value on the code sample

You should provide code that lets us reproduce the issue: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kPfOpR

@tim thats the thing, Ive tried replicating the code on online compilers (exactly the same as yours) but it works just fine. im not sure if its an environment problem or a setting problem that i need to look into. Any other things that might be affecting how it works?

But you don't even provide the relevant code. You say that "，" is the issue but in your code it's an empty string. Copy&Paste the string value from the debugger here. The part about the "weird thing" is also not clear to me. That code does not make any sense.

Pardon me for not being thorough, but the code is exactly the same as your code. the str is a parameter from another method so I just missed my chance to put it there on my question

In your question is now a different comma than in my  .net fiddle. It's important to copy&paste the value from your debugger and not just guess what it is. Are you sure that the code is executed in the If or if it just looks so? Maybe you run in release mode and not in debug mode.

@tim I already added the value on the sample code. I also just realized that the value you used in fiddle is a half-width comma with a single space ", ", but the value that I used was a full-width comma "，". And Im not sure how else to explain the weird thing, its just as what i wrote in the post, even when the equation returns a false value, the code in the If statement stilll gets executed and I dont understand why.

Im running it on debug mode.

Option Compare Text will cause this.
Option Compare Text

Imports System

Public Module Demo
    Public Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("，" = ",")
    End Sub
End Module


True

(see demo)
You should unset it at the project level.

This has solved it! I understand now! Thank you so much!
